# Plugins failed to Load during Jira startup after upgrade to 7. 1.6

Tags: plugins, jira

I am trying to upgrade to Jira 7 from version 6. I used the rapid upgrade method. It installs fine but I get an error on the browser “There is a problem with your Jira Access”. I went through the logs and I see that 6 plugins are failed to load during the Jira startup. Somehow they are disabled. I replaced couple of these `.jar` files with latest `.jar` and re-started the service, but I get the same error.

I also ran this query `update pluginstate set pluginenabled='true'` in the db but no luck.

Here is the log:

```
net.customware.plugins.connector.salesforce.salesforce-connector-plugin' - 'ServiceRocket Salesforce.com Connector Plugin - Plugin' failed to load.
Cannot start plugin: net.customware.plugins.connector.salesforce.salesforce-connector-plugin
Unresolved constraint in bundle net.customware.plugins.connector.salesforce.salesforce-connector-plugin [206]: Unable to resolve 206.0: missing requirement [206.0] osgi.wiring.bundle; (osgi.wiring.bundle=net.customware.plugins.connector.atlassian.jira-connector-plugin) [caused by: Unable to resolve 204.0: missing requirement [204.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.rpc)]
```

It was loaded from `C:\JIRA_data\plugins\installed-plugins\salesforce-connector-plugin-6.0.8.jar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem last week, upgrading from 6.4.13 to 7.1.6. There are some incompatible plugins that crash Jira 7 when started, despite an apparently successful upgrade. Please refer to this page for details on the target plugins, as well as a way to solve the problem:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/upgrading-to-jira-7-throws-a-nosuchmethoderror-on-com-atlassian-crowd-embedded-api-user-781396615.html

Comment: After removing those plugins from the installed plugins folder,errors related to plugins went away but I am still seeing other errors like  "No such method" , "Bean Creation Exception" and "LazyReferences$IntializationException"